# Cannot serve node application

Tags: networking, redhat, node.js

I cannot hit this node application from the browser `52.138.7.79 refused to connect.` but i can load up nginx on 80 fine. also i can hit it on the machine using curl. This is running on a Azure Vm and the port is open, the rhel firewall is disabled ... any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Port 8080 redirected/openned ?

Comment: Your node app bound to 127.0.0.1 instead of any address. You'll have to find the part of your code that handles opening the socket for listening and look up how to change it.

Comment: I had the wrong `server_name` in the conf file